# How to pass an object as QueryString to web api using Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new to Axios and have problem in the simple question.

My React code:

```
const params = {
      "id": "1",
      "name":"Mike"
  };
  axios.request({
      url: 'https://localhost:44343/api/SampleData/test',
      method: 'get',
      data:params
  })
```

My asp.net core web api:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public async Task Test([FromQuery]Model model)
```

My model:

```
public class Model
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I failed to pass the js object as query string to my api code. `model` data is null for `Id` and `Name`.

Comment: what is the error you are receiving

Comment: no error,just null for `model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

  const params = {
      "id": "1",
      "name":"Mike"
  };
  axios.request({
      url: 'https://localhost:44343/api/SampleData/test?' + querystring.stringify(params),
      method: 'get',
      data:params
  })
```